# File Download from web site contains the site's HTML, not the intended data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, download

I am working on an ASP.Net/VB.Net web application in which a file is to be generated and sent to the client when a button on the page is clicked. I have the following code to do this:-

```
Dim text_file_name As String = WriteOutputFile()   ' Generate output file

Response.ClearContent()
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + text_file_name + ";")
Response.Flush()
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() 

File.Delete(text_file_name)
```

This appears to complete and a file is duly downloaded, but on opening it I find it contains the web page HTML, rather than the intended file text. I observe though that the file (extension .csv) is opened up in Excel, so it is getting at least that part of the message.

I have verified that the file is created as intended by leaving out the File.Delete and watching the files accumulate in the server's directory.

In a previous attempt I had

```
Response.End()
```

in place of the complete request; this also generated a .csv file, but one containing the details of a thread exception.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Read the HTML. It'll contain an exception message and stack trace. Or ... you never send the file.

Comment: Your second and third lines reset the HTTP buffer clearing everything out. Later you send a _hint_ header with a _hint_ file name. But I don't actually see you sending any data.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, so this AddHeader function doesn't add anything, then?

Comment: That's correct, it just instructs the browser what you want to the file to be named when pushing your data.

Comment: There's a `Response.WriteFile()` that you can use to send the binary contents a file

Comment: @ChrisHaas, righto. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending the intended file name to the browser as a header *hint* but you aren't actually sending the file itself. To do that, use [`Response.WriteFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you that; it has been partly successful. The file data is now sent over, but it still has the web page's HTML attached to the bottom of it. Do you know how to fix that (perhaps I should raise another question)?